# Use Rust trait object with generic method

Tags: generics, rust, trait-objects

I am trying to write a trait describing a client for an HTTP server where I can tie the response to the query type:

```rs
trait Query {
  type Output;
}

trait ApiClient {
  fn send<Q: Query>(&self, q: &Q) -> Q::Output
  where
    Self: Sized;
}
```

I am able to write and use it when it is implemented for a type known at compile time. However I would like to use it from a trait object:

```rs
fn test_api_client(client: &dyn ApiClient) {
  impl Query for u32 {
    type Output = u32;
  }

  let query: u32 = 10;
  let output = client.send(&query);
  dbg!(output);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1babc2d36f1b1b596199dc08d2415d4f)

The playground code fails with the following error:

```
error: the `send` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
  --> src/main.rs:38:23
   |
12 |     Self: Sized;
   |           ----- this has a `Sized` requirement
...
38 |   let output = client.send(&query);
   |                       ^^^^
```

Is there a workaround to wrap this generic method so it can be used through a trait object? I tried implementing it on `&T` where `T: ApiClient` because `&dyn ApiClient` is sized even if `dyn ApiClient` is not but wasn't able to use it.

I found that I can use `Iterator::map` through a trait object, despite this method being generic:

```rs
fn test(it: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = u8>) {
  for i in it.map(|x| x + 1) {
    dbg!(i);
  }
}
```

This is the `Iterator::map` implementation:

```rs
    #[inline]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B,
    {
        Map::new(self, f)
    }
```

How can I achieve a similar result as the standard library for `Iterator`?

Comment: The usual workaround is to redesign the trait to support object safe methods. The example with the iterator works because the trait `Iterator` [is explicitly implemented for `&mut I` where `I` can be an unsized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13), and that implementation does not depend on the non-object-safe methods of the trait object internally.